# UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout reloading

Tags: ios, delegates, uicollectionview

Is there a way to re-layout the cells in a UICollectionView WITHOUT calling the data source methods? i.e just re-applying the flow layout

Comment: You can invalidate your flowlayout which will reload the layout of the collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

```
[self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]
```

And that should do it.

Comment: that works nicely,but the visible cells are then the new size, but the old class

Comment: So, what is the problem ? If you invalidate the layout after you change your layout that is what it is supposed to do, change the size, the way you have defined. Or, is there anything else that I dont get.